# Kafka connect RabbitMQ unable to use insert field transform: Only Struct objects supported for [field insertion], found: [B

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to use the `InsertField` kafka connect transformation with rabbitmq connector.
my configuration:

```
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.rabbitmq.RabbitMQSourceConnector",
        "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:29092",
        "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 1,
        "topic.creation.default.partitions": 1,
        "tasks.max": "2",
        "kafka.topic": "test",
        "rabbitmq.queue": "events",
        "rabbitmq.host": "rabbitmq",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "transforms": "InsertField",
        "transforms.InsertField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.field": "MessageSource",
        "transforms.InsertField.static.value": "Kafka Connect framework"
    }
```

I have also tried using `BytesArrayConverter` as the value. Using python, I send a message as follows:

```
        msg = json.dumps(body)
        self.channel.basic_publish(exchange="", routing_key="events", body=msg)
```

where using `encode()` to transform it into a byte array does not work as well.
The exception I'm receiving is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Struct objects supported for [field insertion], found: [B
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireStruct(Requirements.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField.applyWithSchema(InsertField.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField.apply(InsertField.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
    ... 11 more
```

I understand the error and thought that using `JsonConverter` will solve it, but I was wrong. I've also used `"value.converter.schemas.enable" : "false"` to no avail.
Would appreciate any help. I don't mind sending the data in json form or bytes form, I just want a key:value pair to be added to the event.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can only insert fields into structs. To get a Struct from RabbitMQ String/Bytes schemas, you must chain a HoistField transform before InsertField one.

To get any Struct from JSONConverter, your JSON needs two top level fields named `schema` and `payload`, then connector needs

```
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

Alternatively, use Kafka headers for "source" information, rather than trying to inject into the value

Comment: Thanks for the response. Won't using a HoistField create a top level key:value if I'm sending a json as the message? and regarding headers - i'm open to the idea. I'll give it a go, as i see that logstash can present these headers and I will be able to manipulate them

Comment: not sure if I should open a new question, but configuration taken straight from the documentation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertheader.html#description does not work

Comment: Yes, that's what hoisting does. Basically, the problem is that your JSON is only a string, as far as Connect is concerned, therefore it doesn't know if it has existing key/values or not unless you explicitly define the schema.

Comment: I've not used the insert header transform before, but I think header.converter is a property that might be needed

Comment: Unfortunately, as per docs, InsertHeader isn't available for managed connectors. I'll try HoistField and accept your answer on success

Comment: As mentioned, you could also change your Python code (Rabbit producer client?) to use `schema` + `payload` JSON records